# Disable Designer for a derived class in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-forms-designer

I have class A derived from a Windows.Form class, using the VS2008 designer. When I double click on the file name in Visual Studio Solution Explorer, the form designer opens. This is the desired behavior.

I have a second class B, derived from A (manually). This class is pure code - it adds some functionality but the form is the same - but if I double click on its file name in Visual Studio Solution Explorer, it opens the form designer. **This is the undesired behavior**, particularly as I will need to produce similarly derived classes C-Z.

Is there a way of forcing the file to always open in the code editor? I'm aware of two proposed workarounds:

1. Give class B the attribute:  [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory("")]

   This appears to have worked in the past according to various postings, but doesn't seem to have any effect in my situation. The VS environment still tries to open a form designer for the class.
2. Rename the source file to meaningfulname.Designer.cs

   This... well, it just isn't nice, is it?

Should solution (1) still work? If so, what might I be doing wrong?

Or is there another solution?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try to use `[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory("Code")]`  instead.

Comment: I tried this too, but without success. The moment B is set to derive from A, the environment classifies it as a GUI class. Remove the base class, and it toggles back.

Comment: @MZB: It seems you have to use the fully qualified name in the attribute, are you sure you are doing this? Otherwise I am out of suggestions.

Comment: A genius, sir! You were correct. Having imported System.ComponentModel I was not using the fully qualified path. A strange Microsoftian bug...

Comment: @MZB: You're welcome. Have you considered awarding the bounty? It will cost you 50 points anyway...